# Type safety warning when I put a LinkedList inside an array

Tags: java

I have declare an array like this:

```
LinkedList< Interval>[] resTable = new LinkedList[10];
```

How do I declare this somehow to avoid the type safety warning which shows inside eclipse?

Here is the warning:

> Type safety: The expression of type LinkedList[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to LinkedList< Interval>[]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java how to: Generic Array creation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Comment: Use a `List`. Specifically, you probably want `ArrayList`. `List<List<Interval>> resTable = new ArrayList<>();`. Probably you want some kind of table class.

Comment: You already had the easiest solution, i added a post how to supress the warning

Comment: (Tom Hawtin - tackline) using the List does not solve the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays of generics are not type safe, as generics are implemented by erasure.

You will need to cast to indicate that it is safe.

See this question for more details: [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/java-how-to-generic-array-creation)

Short answer: consider using

```
ArrayList< LinkedList<Interval> >
```

instead. The ArrayList class takes care of the generics, and the code will be clean and reliable, without the need for unchecked casts.

Comment: although this is not a straight answer to this post but that help me alot. thnx

Comment: @Mehdi I've added a simple solution, too: use an arraylist instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

It simply a Eclipse warning that you can ignore, or mark to ignore:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
LinkedList<Integer>[] tableX = new LinkedList[10];
tableX[3].add(3);
```

I used Integer instead of Interval, such that i could compile the code.

Comment: I know about the annotation @ SuppressWarnings... to avoid the warning, what I want is a way to write the code to avoid these kinda warning without even use @ SuppressWarning. 
In fact this annotation just avoid showing the warning but It does not solve the problem .
Anyways thank you 4 your post man